# HTML parsing - Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html

I got HTML tags saved in column as :

<p><strong>Alva Beach Markets from 8.00am to 1.00pm.&#160; For more information contact Monika Chapple on 0428 649 472.</strong></p>

But when bind it to Label out is showing whole HTML tags instead the inner text.

How should i parse this before binding to label control.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to parse it out or display it using that html?

Comment: Yes need to bind it label control.

Comment: So you need to show Alva Beach Markets from 8:00AM to 1:00PM and nothing else, no html, etc... in the label control?  Or do you want to show the text with the HTML around it on the web page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the literal control not a label.  The label control ignores markup and spits out exactly what it is given as text.  The literal will return the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Weird, someone had replied with 'use a literal control', but their post is gone now. Anyway, what's what you should do.

-- Edit:

And now it's back again. Disregard me.

Comment: Don't feel crazy... I actually deleted it and then undeleted it just as fast.